# Prove that {$ A \bigcap x : x\in B $} is a set

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, axioms

How can I prove that {$ A \bigcap x : x\in B $} is a set when A and B are sets?

I have to use set theory axioms.

Comment: Is $B$ a collection of sets?

Comment: I am confused. Doesn't the use of the curly parentheses already indicate it is a set? Do those set theory axioms spell out certain conditions under which something is a set? Or when something is not a set?

Comment: $A\cap x$ might be a set if $x$ is a set. That would make your set a collection of separate intersections.

Comment: @MPW it says its a set, nothing more.

Comment: The expression "$A\bigcap x$" doesn't make sense unless $A$ is a set and each $x\in B$ is a set. And if those conditions are indeed satisfied, then the entire expression is the collection of all of those sets $A\bigcap x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a subset (COMPREHENSION) of the POWER SET of the UNION SET of B.

Comment: And why does that mean it's a set?

Comment: Prove the existence of a set in set theory is to construct it through the axioms from the sets we have.